# What's the problem with my password while installing Apex 20.1?

Tags: oracle, installation, windows, password

I am installing Apex 20.1 on my windows 10 with oracle 19c.  After running the command : *@apxchpwd.sql*  I get this error even after respecting all the password regulation and trying different combinations of mails and passwords :

````
User "ADMIN" does not yet exist and will be created.
Enter ADMIN's email [ADMIN] 
Enter ADMIN's password []
ERROR:
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated


declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: Invalid password.
ORA-06512: at line 30
ORA-06512: at "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_FND_USER_INT", line 3723
ORA-06512: at line 20```
````

Comment: Looks like you used a single quote as a special character, and it blew up the SQL. In general, the only special character that doesn't cause problems with any OS or client interface that I am aware of is the underscore ( _ ). Depending on the client interface and the underlying OS, other special characters may introduce unintended special meaning to the command line, like terminating a quoted string prematurely.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The idea is that I didnt use any quotations at all in any field , thats why i dont understand where the problem come from.